# Элемент в системном объекте (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Положил в системный объект DOM элемент.

Вывожу в консоль `xhr`, который имеет элемент `progressbar`.
Но `this.progressbar` - `undefined`. Почему?

```
var File = {



    add: function() {

        let form = document.createElement('input');
        form.type = 'file';
        form.click();

        form.onchange = function() {

            File.upload(this.files[0])

            .Before(function() { this.progressbar =
            document.querySelector('progress'); })

            // Туть undefined, хотя this показывает его наличие
            .Progress(function() { console.log(this.progressbar); });
        }
    },



    upload: function(file) {

        let form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', file);

        function post(xhr) {

            xhr.open('POST', window.location.origin);

            xhr.Before = function(c) { xhr.Before = c; return this; };
            xhr.Progress = function(c) { xhr.Progress = c; return this; };



            /*
                Before
            */

            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if (xhr.readyState == 2)
                try { xhr.Before.call(xhr, xhr); } catch { }
            }



            /*
                Progress
            */

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {

                try {

                    let percent = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                    xhr.Progress.call(xhr, percent, e.loaded, e.total);

                } catch { }
            }



            xhr.send(form);

            return xhr;
        }

        return post(new XMLHttpRequest());
    }
}
```

---

```
<button onclick='File.add()'>добавить файл</button>
<progress max='100' value='64'></progress>
```

Comment: что значит _Туть undefined, хотя this показывает его наличие_?

Comment: @Grundy `.Before(function() { записал элемент в XMLHttpRequest })` - он там есть, но `.Progress(function() { здесь вывожу this и вижу progressbar, но this.progressbar здесь не находит })`

Comment: @Grundy, только что проверил, что это не из-за системного объекта `XMLHttpRequest`, а с любым

Comment: сколько раз срабатывает `log` внутри `progress`?

Comment: @Grundy учитывая, что выбираю маленький файл, то 1 раз. Но попробовал большой файл, и раз 10 `undefined` сработал, так что, думаю, дело не в асинхронности

Comment: @Grundy Это всё из-за `xhr.upload.onprogress`. Если использовать другие события, то объект находится, но именно из-за `upload` нет доступа. Может это как-то связано с безопасностью браузера 

Comment: нет, не должно, нужно как-то воспроизвести

Comment: @Grundy нашёл причину. `Before` срабатывает после `Progress`

Comment: Напиши ответ тогда

Comment: @Grundy не могу, нужно определить `Before` до отправки. Пытаюсь использовать `promise`. Через `setTimeout` не очень хочется делать

Comment: добавь лог в `xhr.onreadystatechange` и посмотри какие статусы у тебя до upload начинаются

Comment: @Grundy При отправке инициализируется XMLHttpRequestUpload (тут же работает сразу Progress), потом `readyState` 2, 3, 4. Поэтому `Progress` перед `Before` срабатывает

Comment: а что тебе мешает задать обработчики до вызова `send`?

Comment: @Grundy то что `Before` может и не быть. В этом и трудность, всё должно быть асинхронно. Событие `onloadstart` в этом не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала отправлялась форма `xhr.send(form)`, затем возвращался объект `return xhr`.
Событие `xhr.upload.onprogress` выполнялось первым, затем `readyState` менялся на **2**, **3** и **4**.

Так как инициализация прогресса выполнялась первой, естественно объект не был найден. Было решено сменить событие и отправлять сперва объект, затем форму.

```
/*
    Before
*/

xhr.onloadstart = function() {

    try { xhr.Before.call(xhr, xhr); } catch { }
}
```

---

```
setTimeout(() => xhr.send(form));
return xhr;
```

Comment: Так и не пойму почему `upload.onprogress` срабатывает перед `readyState 2`. Тоесть происходит отправка файла (upload.onprogress), потом заголовки (2), ответ от сервера (3) и завершение (4)

Comment: readyState 2. - это HEADERS_RECEIVED - то есть когда ты получил заголовки с сервера, а не отправляешь. Ну и в любом случае непонятно почему ты хочешь устанавливать обработчики после посылки запроса. Просто добавь к методам `Before`, `Progress` еще метод `Send` который бы и отправлял запрос

Comment: @Grundy Типа так `Request(data).send();`? Хотелось без лишних методов сделать `Request(data);`

Comment: Ты уже делаешь с лишними методами Before и Progress

Comment: @Grundy это не лишние методы. Есть простые запросы, а есть загрузка файлов, где нужно показать прогресс. А где ещё это сделать, если не в этих методах? Нужно же найти прогрессбар и задавать ему значение выполненного процесса [gif](https://imgur.com/qnQIEtV)

Comment: Эти методы лишние, так как ты вызываешь их **после** запуска запроса.

Comment: @Grundy эти методы опциональные и необязательные, поэтому запрос выглядит так `Request(data)` или `File.upload(file)`. Сейчас я сделал проще - progressbar опциональный метод  `File.upload( file ).progressbar( document.querySelector('progress') )` 

Comment: Ты мог их просто параметрами передавать `Request(data, before, progress)` и тогда никаких проблем не было бы, потому что все методы доступны до формирования запроса.

Comment: @Grundy конечно мог бы, но а что делать, если мне before не нужен, а нужен только progress. Получается какаха `Request(data, null, progress)`. И ещё неизвестно сколько методов понадобится

Comment: Ты можешь проверить что тебе передали, а что нет и использовать функцию по умолчанию или вообще ничего не вызывать, если нужный параметр не передали

Comment: @Grundy да я делал раньше так, отдавал вместо аргументов объект с функциями `Progress`, `Before` и т.д., но в самом объекте `Request` из-за этого каша была. Приходилось выяснять где запрос, где данные, а где функции. Ты бы это видел, я там так в коде нагадил года 3 назад 

Comment: У тебя и сейчас все смешано, собственно из-за этого и проблемы :)

Comment: @Grundy возможно, через 3 годика посмотрю на это. Нет предела совершенству 